# LP with n free variables can be replaced by n + 1 nonnegative variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I need to prove that if an LP has n free variables, that these n free variables can be replaced by n + 1 nonnegative variables.

If an LP has one free variable $x_1$ this is clear to me, write $x_1 = x_1^+ - x_1^-$, with $x_1^+$ and $x_1^-$ being two nonnegative variables.

I tried to prove this for n free variables using induction, but could not see how I could use the induction hypothesis in the induction step, since the LP from the induction step has one free variable more than the LP from the induction hypothesis and I could not see how you could relate these to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it directly (without induction) by replacing each free variable $x_i$ with $x_i^+ -x_1^-$, where $x_i^+ \ge 0$ and $x_1^- \ge 0$.  If all $x_i \ge 0$, you can take $x_1^- = 0$; otherwise, you can take $x_1^- = -\min\limits_{i: x_i < 0} x_i$.

Comment: RobPratt When we replace each unrestricted variable with two non-negative, we can not have both of those parts at a positive level simultaneously. However when we use the above answered strategy I think we lose this assertion, is this correct?

Comment: @Upstart Even in the formulation with $2n$ nonnegative variables there is no "complementarity" requirement that at most one of the two nonnegative variables for $x_i$ is positive.